# GLWidget in Qt only updating on mousemove

Tags: user-interface, qt, opengl, animation

I am currently playing with Qt trying to set up a small particle system.  Therein I've subclassed the GLWidget and hacked away at it.  Everything was going well until I made some unknown change and now the widget only repaints when I move the mouse (it should be doing it all the time due to the QTimer I have firing).  Relevant code:

OpenGLWidget.h

```
class OpenGLWidget :  public QGLWidget  {

   Q_OBJECT

public:
   OpenGLWidget(QWidget * parent = 0);
   ~OpenGLWidget();

public slots:
   void toggleEmitter();

protected:
   void initializeGL();
   void paintGL();
   void resizeGL(int width, int height);
   QSize minimumSizeHint() const;
   QSize sizeHint() const;
   void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
   void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event);

protected slots:
   void timeOut();

private:

   void testFunc(Particle & p, unsigned int t);

   QTime time;
   QTimer timer;

   Emitter emitter;
```

Relevant code from the .cpp

```
// in the constructor
time.start();
connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(timeOut()));
timer.start(0);

void OpenGLWidget::initializeGL()  {
   GLuint tex = 0;

   qglClearColor(bgColor);
   glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);   
   glClearDepth(1.0f);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
   glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH); 

   glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
   glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); 
   glEnable( GL_BLEND );
   glBlendFunc( GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE); // _MINUS_SRC_ALPHA );

   glPointSize(3.0f);

   tex = bindTexture(QPixmap(QString("testparticle2.png")), GL_TEXTURE_2D);
   emitter = Emitter(Vector(0, 0, 0.0f), tex, 50, fastdelegate::FastDelegate2<Particle &, unsigned int>(this, &OpenGLWidget::testFunc));
}

void OpenGLWidget::paintGL()  {
   makeCurrent();
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

   mainCam.SetView();

   glRotatef(xRot, 1, 0, 0);
   glRotatef(yRot, 0, 1, 0);

   emitter.Process(time.elapsed());

   totalTime += time.elapsed();
   time.restart();

}

void OpenGLWidget::resizeGL(int width, int height)  {
   contextWidth = width;
   contextHeight = height;

   glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity();
   gluPerspective(55.0f, width / (float) height, 0.01f, 100.0f);

   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   glLoadIdentity();

}

void OpenGLWidget::timeOut()  {
   updateGL();
}

void OpenGLWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)  {
    lastX = event->pos().x();
    lastY = event->pos().y();
}

void OpenGLWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)  {
    int dx = event->x() - lastX;
    int dy = event->y() - lastY;

    if (event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) {
        xRot += 3 * dy;
        yRot += 3 * dx;
    } else if (event->buttons() & Qt::RightButton) {
        xRot += 3 * dy;
        yRot += 3 * dx;
    }

    lastX = event->pos().x();
    lastY = event->pos().y();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A QTimer with 0 second time out only fires when the event loop gets the control. I suspect this is not the case. However, when you move the mouse, the event loop processes some events (again) and then delivers the pending timer event(s). Maybe you need to invoke [processEvents()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) in your update loop to make sure that the pending timer event from QTimer gets processed.

Answer (score 1):

considering that updateGL() calls glDraw() which calls paintGL(), you'd think the timer should be calling the same functionality as your mousemove event.

Are you sure the timer is actually ticking?

BTW, there is no need to call makeCurrent() in [paintGL()](http://doc.trolltech.com/3.3/qglwidget.html#paintGL).

edit: after the extra information was added:

[QTimer says](http://doc.trolltech.com/3.3/qtimer.html):

> "As a special case, a QTimer with
>   timeout 0 times out as soon as all the
>   events in the window system's event
>   queue have been processed."

so, if you want it to go as fast as possible (though 10ms is probably the minimum on Windows and most x386-based systems), then start your timer with a value of 1 instead of 0. I assume that this is the problem, that its only ticking when it has *finished* reading off messages from the queue.

Comment: makeCurrent was there for debugging purposes.  It turns out the timer is ticking but the time step is not updating correctly except when the mouse is being moved.

Comment: Try a non-zero time step? 1/60th of a second is ~17 msec.

Answer (score 1):

Timer simply can't work with less than 20ms. It's equals 0 for it. You may use simple loop with measuring time from one iteration to another. Measuring method probably should use API of your operation system.